# sql select top n values - ordering and limiting by a value for multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to understand the logic to output a certain number of top values (say 2) for multiple columns. 
The table looks somewhat like this: there are different classes, subjects and students. i want to know how to look at only the top 2 students by mars scored for each subject and class

example of the table:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Szr.jpg)

and so on

What the output should look like:
[image: result output]

Comment: It's much easier for others when you just type out your data instead of linking pictures.  Your first link is broken so no one is going to be able to answer this question for you.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select class, subject, student_id, marks_scored
from (
  select class, subject, student_id, marks_scored, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by subject, class order by marks_scored desc) as rnk
  from the_table
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by class, subject, marks_scored desc;
```

---

If there is more than one student with the same score, all those students would be listed. So this *can* return more than two "top students".

If you don't want that, replace `dense_rank()` with `row_number()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have never used window functions before. Will try to read more about it.